# If the question or an answer is flagged then why don't we send a message to the OP?

Tags: feature-request, flags

I wanted to know if someone flagged a question or an answer for any reason, like it is a spam or it is abusive or ...reasons then can't we send a message to the OP so that the OP understands that people are not liking the post or it is of low quality or it is abusive etc., etc.?

Maybe if someone has not intentionally put his words correctly (as many of the users are not native English speakers here) but since the OP has not put his question/answer/comments correctly hence it is being flagged!

Comment: Consider that I'd rather *not* have the OP be notified that there are flags/votes to migrate as they may take that as a suggestion to repost instead.

Comment: Yes I understand that but what about the case when the question/answer/comment is to be deleted by Modertor because it is being flagged for the reasons mentioned in the list or may be a custom reason. I know that using COMMENTS in that case is a better option but what if the comment is deleted!

Comment: Just thinking of some of my flags that have lead to deleted questions (and accounts) - do you really want someone who was spamming links to their blogs to be made aware that its been flagged? Or someone noticed some sock puppetry?  Or for that matter, on the occasion is *misflag* a question (wrong window open or thought I saw something I didn't?) - no need to add to the stress / consternation of another user (I'm sure I cause enough amongst the mods as it is).

Comment: @MichaelT:- Yes I agree with your point but there are also who are not native English speakers and personally speaking (I am an Indian and I am also not a native English speaker) and I have dealt with many such users who dont know English(to put there thoughts) and then they end up writing comments in Hindi(mother toungue of India) which according to SO is SPAM as it is not relevant to all. P.S. Infact I flag those comments in Hindi as SPAM

Comment: ONLY TWO PEOPLE HAVE ANSWERED AND 4 downvotes. REQUEST TO DOWNVOTERS do care to leave a comment or answer so that I dont have to flag this question to be deleted because of heave downvoting ;)

Comment: @RahulTripathi - I believe that people are downvoting due to a disagreement with the feature request, not to indicate that it's a bad question.

Comment: @BradLarson:- Sorry ...I got the wrong definition of feature request. Updated that. Thanks!

Comment: @RahulTripathi The question inherently is requesting a feature, so it should be tagged as a feature request.  Mis-tagging it as something else doesn't change what it is, or how people should vote on it.

Comment: @Servy:- My concern is not about the downvotes or upvotes. I really felt bad for some of the people here in my country who really find it difficult in converting there thoughts in English and I find myself as a culprit when people put there comments as not constructive just because its in Hindi(I am sorry if the question is stupid) but I just felt bad about it!

Comment: Okay.  What does that have to do with whether the question is tagged as a feature request or not?

Comment: I am not sure about the tags which I should put this for the question. I am really sorry for that. I just wanted to know that when people comment in other(there native language) then how it should be handled. I thought that sending them a message could be an idea before deleting there questions/answers/comments(but I think that is a bad idea)

Comment: You understand that there are many reasons other than a non-English comment for a flag? And that you asked about flags on questions or answers, not comments? And that a feature to notify about all flags could not really help with your specific situation? You can always leave a comment in that situation and it is likely to be a helpful thing to do

Comment: @KateGregory:- Yes I think I agree with your answer and with your comments! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not all flags are accurate. Consider:

- the flag is wrong. Nothing will happen to the post and there was no need to tell the user and upset them. This is probably the minority of the cases.
- the flag is right. A moderator will decide whether to leave the user a comment (which will notify them with the red circle) or not. It depends on the action the moderator chooses to take.
- another flag comes in on the same post before a moderator has handled the first
- the flag may be about something else. For example, when there's a bad review of a suggested edit review some people flag the question (because you can't flag the review) for moderators to check the edit and review history. This would confuse the owner of the question because the flag has nothing to do with anything the OP has done or not done.
- flags are sometimes a favour to the user, not a request for deletion or punishment. I have flagged in the past to help a user recover their own lost accounts, for example, and reconnect old questions to the new account. If the notification contained any of the details from the flag, it might break privacy issues, including investigations of deliberate cheating, and if it didn't then the user might think something bad was happening when that is not always the case.

Notifying about a flag is like sending someone a letter that says *"you might be in trouble. It's not possible for you to participate in the decision process about your guilt or your punishment. You'll find out later if there will be any consequences. It might be a few minutes, or tomorrow, or even longer. Or actually nothing at all might happen and you might not have done anything wrong. We're just looking into something."* Would you enjoy getting a letter like that?

If you want to leave a comment for the user at the same time as you flag, go ahead. I did a lot of that before I got tired of it. I think it even helped a few users. But for the system to do so would not be pleasant or useful.

Comment: +1 That answers really well but as I commented above there are also some users who are not native English speakers and personally speaking (I am an Indian and I am also not a native English speaker) and I have dealt with many such users who dont know English(to put there thoughts) and then they end up writing comments in Hindi(mother toungue of India) which according to SO is SPAM as it is not relevant to all. P.S. Infact I flag those comments in Hindi as SPAM

Comment: I am not sure how that comment (which I read above) is relevant to my answer. If you know a comment isn't trying to sell something, don't flag as spam, flag as not constructive. And leave them a comment saying to comment in English only please. If they have provided relevant information and you feel able to translate, you could always comment "what OP's comment means in English is: ..."

Comment: Here's a fun one to consider... the flag may be about *something else*.  When there's a bad suggested edit review (for example) on a question, one is to flag the question (because you can't flag the review).  This would make notification to the owner of the question go "huh?"

Comment: @KateGregory:- Can we edit the comments?

Comment: You can delete any of your comments, you can only edit for 5 minutes

Comment: @MichaelT thanks, edited that one into the answer

Comment: It should also be pointed out that many flags contain information that the users in question probably shouldn't see, like evidence that they might be cheating the voting system. We want people to feel free to flag with this, knowing that only moderators will see it. Otherwise it could lead to reprisals against the flagger.

Comment: Historical note: originally, flags were visible to many/most users *right on the post* (the way close votes are now). Authors tended to freak out about this (which made them an effective tool for harassment, thus making the problem *worse!*)

Answer (score 3):

You may look at a flag as a suggestion, it may have been not validated yet.

Mostly the OP doesn't want to be informed about any flag, and if one is useful, then the OP will notice when an action will be taken.

There are various of other useful ways (like comments, downvotes etc.) to make the OP's notice a potential improvement/issue with his post, and his responsibility is to pay attention to those signs after posting the question.